# Silverlight control layout update in runtime

Tags: silverlight, layout, animation, controls

I have a silverlight control that has a few element such as: Image, TextBox and a TextBlock.

The application shows a list of the same control and the controls are placed in a specific layout, in grid with rows and cols.

Now,

I would like to be able to modify all the controls layout and arrange the element differently (preferred animatedly) without reloading the control.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Thanks,
   Ronny

Comment: A small sample of the original XAML along with the changes you would like to make would help, question is a bit abstract at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the States pane in
   Expression Blend 3 to define different
   layouts.
2. Use the GoToStateAction for the objects/events that you want to trigger the change or call VisualStateManager:GoToState(this, "NewState", true) from your code behind to switch layouts.
3. Use FluidLayout (the wave-shaped first button first for the State Group) to animate the change from one grid col/row to another.

Comment: Great way to modify the layout :)

But I have the elements organized in a grid. How can I modify the elements location (changing the row and the col) and still animate them to their new location?

I'm using the grid auto width and height because the size of the element in unknown and I would like to change their location and still keep the "stretch" functionality.

Comment: I added a third item for what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but when I turned the fluidlayout on, I got ag_e_parser_bad_type exception

Comment: This is for Silverlight 3 - do you have SL 3 installed?